# Siverlight talk to server using WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I am doing an simple  Siverlight app  talk to server using WCF.When I run the app in visual studio,it works fine .However,when I hosted unders IIS,the data from the server will never returned.
Can anyone shine some light on this and how can I debug silverlight app with WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [fiddler](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/03/31/silverlight-and-wcf-essentials-fiddler/).
or enable wcf logging on a website that hosts your service, which will give you even more information. Read more [here](http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/06/15/silverlight-and-wcf-wcf-logs-and-debugging/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any kind of response from the server at all? Are your silverlight applications configured to reference the correct web services (not the visual studio web server)? Can you browse to your WCF services in the browser and get a response?
www.example.com/myservice.svc

Just a few ideas...

Comment: Are you receiving any kind of response from the server at all? 
Do not think so
Are your silverlight applications configured to reference the correct web services (not the visual studio web server)? 
Yes
Can you browse to your WCF services in the browser and get a response?
Yes
It works fine when in visual studio.When hosted in IIS.I add the service reference for the service hosted in IIS and stops working.I can browse to the service and I even create a non-silverlight client to consume the service ,it works fine.How can I debug the silverlight when hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Use Attach to process. Remember Silverlight is running on the client so you can open the app in IE and then attach visual studio to it.

You may also want to look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check the traffic is going to the right place.

Comment: Can you tell more about how to use Attaching to process.It does not seems that I can debug silverlight using Attaching to process.